# Running multiple React projects using nvm: Yarn start and/or npm start freezes on Mac M1 pro

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, nvm, apple-m1

I have multiple React projects. All using different versions of Node.js. I have installed `nvm`.

Now, when I run `yarn start` or `npm start`, the development server just freezes up indefinitely. Tried searching for possible workarounds or solutions for it, but no luck.

It's an M1 MacBook Pro with 16GB RAM.

Comment: Could you show your error message

Comment: no error messages. it just freezes off !! I do `yarn start` -> it shows `starting developing server` and from this point it freezes off.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the `node_modules` and start from new

Comment: yup. I did. I also cleaned `cache` of both `yarn` and `nvm` and then tried it out. Still no luck .. !!